# No Oracle Button in QGIS Data Source Manager on Linux

Tags: qgis, oracle-dbms, linux

I'm using QGIS 3.10 on a system with Fedora 30 Linux.

In the Data Source Manager is the button for Oracle-database-connections missing. An installation of the same QGIS-version on a Windows-Machine has it.

Do I have possibly to install an Oracle-related package to activate it or is it something with the QGIS-Linux-packaging?

Comment: I think you have to build it from the sources on your linux system, see: https://qtibia.ro/2018/01/15/build/

Comment: No, I use a QGIS-package from Fedora Copr as on qgis.org/downloads indicated.